# Tibco Spotfire: Automation Services vs Scheduled updates - What is the difference between them?

Tags: performance, spotfire

Tibco Spotfire:
Automation Services vs Scheduled updates

Both tools are allowing caching the report in order to improve its performance but I wonder if you guys know the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduled Updates caches the analysis (data , visuals ect) for a quick load time. Automation Services is a services that allows you to perform automated steps on the analysis while opening (IE: Exporting PDFs , Sending Emails , Saving Analysis as Embedded data.

Caching the analysis and Saving the data as embedded are two different things.  Caching will ensure the entire dashboard is readily available in cache resulting in fast load times on webplayer. Saving as embedded saves the underlying data to the dxp as SFBD (spotfire binary data)  files for quick load time of the data when accessed in the webplayer.

Automation services also has the ability to set any amount of refresh and at any intervals while Scheduled updates is a bit more strict, this is due to automation services using a task scheduler and the server to open and perform actions while schedule updates only opens and caches data.

I have a few instances where I use both Automation services to refresh data , send email notifications ect and then Schedule Updates also runs on the same analysis (very large data sets). This allows me to refresh at 8am , 9am , 11am , 1pm , 5pm in automation services and scheduled updates ensure end users webplayer loads immediately.

Comment: and is it possible to cache a prompted report?

Comment: No in both instances Scheduled Updates and Automated Services there can be no prompting as there is no user to choose prompts as the system is performing  the updates.  You can however set up scripting in Automation Services to change document property values, filters ect which can trigger python scripts to set properties dynamically

Comment: The exception is On-Demand data sources but they require a default value not a prompt

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Tyger Guzman said....Scheduled updates are used exclusively for the web player to make projects open faster by caching the data.  Scheduled updates don't help desktop users with load time at all.  That's where Automation Services comes into play.  Yes, you can perform tasks (as described above, which Scheduled Updates don't do), but Automation Services can also be used to cache and make desktop load time faster when the project is connected to an information link and when the information link is setup to hold cache.  Basically you use AS to open a project (i.e. ping an IL), before users open the file.  Because the IL is setup to cache, all subsequent requests to the IL open faster.  AS is the trigger.  Neither AS or SU work with prompts.